# How to authenticate API in swift?

Tags: swift, authentication, http-headers

I am trying to add the tweets in my app.
I have implemented the log in button and trying to access the tweets through search API (Fabric)

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=Himan_dhawan

It shows me Bad authentication error

And then i make authenticated request by adding the authenticate header in the Header by this code

```
    let twitter = Twitter.sharedInstance()
    let oauthSigning = TWTROAuthSigning(authConfig:twitter.authConfig, authSession:twitter.session())
    let authHeaders = oauthSigning.OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials()
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=Himan_dhawan")!)
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = authHeaders
```

But it is still showing me Bad authentication.... 
I got stuck into how to add tweets in your app...
Can any one tell me easiest way to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

```
let authHeaders = oauthSigning.OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials()
let urlHeader: AnyObject? = authHeaders[TWTROAuthEchoAuthorizationHeaderKey]

request.allHTTPHeaderFields = urlHeader
```

SideNote:

For Twitter API. Very less usage in the wild and has minimal support for swift. For swift, to avoid problems as above, i use swifter.
https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter
It does all the work for you once u supply your consumer key etc.

Comment: Why Above code is not working as expected ?why it is showing Bad authentication ?  I am asking this bcs i m close to my target , i just want to authenticate my request ...... i can not able to figure out my issue ....i got stuck

Comment: authheaders is not the key you need. authHeaders[TWTROAuthEchoAuthorizationHeaderKey] is the key you need.

Comment: I have implemented what u have written .....but still it is showing me Bad authentication....what will be the reason for this....do u have any idea??

Answer (score 0):

The Fabric doc's don't quite give you the full picture about creating the OAuth signing headers when wanting to use your own NSMutableURLRequest.

`let authHeaders = oauthSigning.OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials()`

The return `[NSObject : AnyObject]!` dictionary gives you the values you need for the request, what it provides for the headers are different to what needs to be sent with the NSMutableURLRequest.

This is how you should be setting the headers for this request:

```
            let twitter = Twitter.sharedInstance()

            let oauthSigning = TWTROAuthSigning(authConfig:twitter.authConfig, authSession:twitter.session())

            let authHeaders = oauthSigning.OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials()

            let mutableUrlWithUsableUrlAddress = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: usableUrlForRequest)

            mutableUrlWithUsableUrlAddress.addValue(authHeaders[TWTROAuthEchoAuthorizationHeaderKey] as? String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

This sets the required Authorisation Key as a value for the "Authorization" header on the request, opposed to when you pass in the authHeaders dictionary, it gets set for "X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization".

The [Fabric doc's](http://docs.fabric.io/ios/digits/oauth-echo.html) do go into this, but it's slightly more tucked away than it should be.